# ArrayAdapter Filteration works only for first time. Failed on next Input

Tags: listview, android-arrayadapter, android-filter

I've applied a filter on Custom List of ArrayAdapter of objects. I have applied the filteration and it is working only for first time. When i've tried to remove filtered text and enter another, it fails to give me updated data in ListView. Here is my code for it,

*Adapter Class*

```
public class ServiceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ServiceItem> implements Filterable {

private Context mContext;
private List<ServiceItem> serviceItemList;
private List<ServiceItem> nameList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int layoutId;
private ServiceFilter filter;


public ServiceListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ServiceItem> serviceItemList) {
    super(context, resource, serviceItemList);

    this.mContext = context;
    this.serviceItemList = serviceItemList;
    this.layoutId = resource;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    ServiceHolder sHolder = null;

    if (v == null) {

        v = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);

        sHolder = new ServiceHolder();
        sHolder.serviceName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.serviceName);
        sHolder.serviceDetail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.serviceDetail);
        sHolder.serviceImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.serviceImg);
        sHolder.btnGo = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

        v.setTag(sHolder);
    } else {

        sHolder = (ServiceHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ServiceItem serviceItem = getItem(position);
    sHolder.serviceName.setText(serviceItem.getServiceName());
    sHolder.serviceDetail.setText(serviceItem.getServiceDetail());
    sHolder.serviceImg.setImageResource(serviceItem.getServiceImg());

    sHolder.btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });


    return v;
}

static class ServiceHolder {

    TextView serviceName;
    TextView serviceDetail;
    ImageView serviceImg;
    Button btnGo;

}

@Override
public ServiceItem getItem(int position) {
    return serviceItemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new ServiceFilter();
    }
    return filter;

}

private class ServiceFilter extends Filter {


    private static final String TAG = "Filter";

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();


        Log.d(TAG, "Length: " + constraint.toString().length());

        if (constraint != "" && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {

            ArrayList<ServiceItem> filterItems = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<ServiceItem> sItems = new ArrayList<>();

            synchronized (this)
            {
                sItems.addAll(serviceItemList);
            }

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            Log.d(TAG, "To Compare:: " + constraint);

            for (int l = 0; l< sItems.size(); l++) {

                Log.d(TAG, "sItems Size:" + sItems.size());

                ServiceItem sItem = sItems.get(l);
                String name = sItem.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + name);

                if (name.startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Added: " + name);
                    filterItems.add(sItem);
                }

            }
             Log.d(TAG, "Filter Item Size: " + filterItems.size());

            filterResults.count = filterItems.size();
            filterResults.values = filterItems;

        } else {

            synchronized (this) {

                Log.d(TAG, "performFiltering: ORIGINAL ");
                Log.d(TAG, "Filter Item Size: " + serviceItemList.size());

                filterResults.values = serviceItemList;
                filterResults.count = serviceItemList.size();

            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Count:" + filterResults.count);

        return filterResults;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        /*nameList is List<ServiceItem> declared in root class*/

        nameList = (ArrayList<ServiceItem>) results.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        for(int i = 0, l = nameList.size(); i < l; i++)
            add(nameList.get(i));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

}

*EditText TextWatcher Code*:

```
edtFilterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Log.d("Filter", "beforeTextChanged: " +s);
            serviceListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
        }
    });
```

So, i got the result of the filteration only for the first time. Then when i'm trying to change the editText content, it shows me no result in filter items and also log display main serviceItems list size to zero with no items.

Help me out with this, i have already tried so many answers but my result works in this way.

Answer (score 0):

For you kind of information i got it solved with the be

`// Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        serviceItemList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            serviceItemList.addAll(nameList);
        }
        else
        {
            for (ServiceItem si : nameList)
            {
                if (si.getServiceName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    serviceItemList.add(si);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

and the calling method is the same as the previous one just a little change,

```
serviceListAdapter.filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
```

And for more information its not the method that we have to implement from Filter class. Its manual method that works like charm.